# Composer update error in doctrine

Tags: php, composer-php

I tried to do a `composer update` command and got this error. What might be the problem?

It was working well before.

```
[RuntimeException]  
Could not delete /var/www/vhosts/kaikacampus.com/httpdocs/kaikacampus.com/vendor/
doctrine/annotations/phpunit.xml.dist: date_defaut_timezone_get():It is not safe 
to reply on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the 
data.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you 
used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most 
likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for 
now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.
```

[image]

I'm not sure about the suggestion given in the red area as I'm a newbie.

The composer version is: `Composer version 1.0-dev (ffffab37a294f3383c812d0329623f0a4ba45387) 2014-11-05 06:04:18`

Comment: @lukasgeiter please take a look at this.

Comment: Before you try anything else, update composer itself. `composer self-update`

Comment: Another error: `File system exception: composer update failed: the "usr/local/bin/composer" file could not be written`

Comment: try `sudo composer self-update`

Comment: Yes, another error message appears. Programs do often report back errors when they encounter one. It's a common part of their user-interface. The user than actually has to read those messages. It starts with accepting that the requested operation most likely could not be completed which is not nice, as you already put so much effort into executing the command, however, this just can happen. Normally the error messages give further notice what went wrong and all you need to do is to deal with the messages. Which part of the error message is it that you do not understand?

Comment: @lukasgeiter, would it possible to have a chat section?

Comment: @user1012181: Screenshot is nice, but keep in mind that the internet still is a text-based medium (as in hypertext). So it often is useful to (additionally) also have important data like the error message you get as *text* with your question. You can edit your question to improve it.

Comment: @user1012181 Sorry I don't have the time at the moment. I'm sure hakre can help you though

Comment: @hakre: will do it now.

Comment: @user1012181: This sort of worked with the edit, but please add the full error message, it looks that it got cutted. Just give it a little bit more love.

Comment: @hakre: edited with all the warning message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performed the action:

```
mv vendor vendor_old && composer update
```

This saved my day!!!

Comment: sorry was afk. happy new year btw. edit through shell is possible (you normally have even multiple editors in shell, play around a bit and check with which you can work, I normally use the vi command to invoke an editor). -- but this is interesting that you were able to move the file but when you executed composer it couldn't delete. Could you run `composer --version` and report back the version it gives? (you can also put that into your question as additional info, that's good practice, too)

Comment: The composer version is : `1.0-dev`

Comment: isn't there more output? normally this is a full line. there is also a date and a SHA hash. (the version is always 1.0-dev :))

Comment: btw -dev in composer just means something like "current code" or maybe "nightly", that is just the code as-is. like the master branch in git.

Comment: `Composer version 1.0-dev (ffffab37a294f3383c812d0329623f0a4ba45387) 2014-11-05 0       6:04:18`

Answer (score 1):

> What might be the problem?

If you take a look at the screenshots you see a bigger red section (circa the lower half of the screenshot).

It contains an error messages that *starts* about telling what *went* wrong. It then has a colon (":") and after the colon, the reason what the problem is, has been given to you.

It is a common PHP error message, for which references should exist. Both on site as well as on other websites in the internet. As you're inclined to search and research before posting, I assume it's okay I leave the straight forward search operation as an exercise to you.

Let me know if you've got problems to read the screen because of the colors used or the size of the letters.

---

As added your first comment, it looks you're puzzled about where to make the timezone changes, right? The error message is speaking about

> *"the **date.timezone** setting"*

(bold by me). When you don't understand what this means, one thing easy to do in PHP is to prefix it with `php.net/` and enter it into your browser:

> http://php.net/date.timezone

This brings you directly to the documentation of that setting.

Comment: I'm a newbie in composer and laravel. That's why I have a confusion . I dont really know where to make the timezone changes

Comment: If I understood your last comment right, you're puzzled about the timezone setting. I've expanded the answer on that exact topic.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sounds dumb.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you. But how can I make the changes?

Comment: What do you mean? Which changes do you want to make? What is it that you're trying?

Comment: I found the location for php.ini. It is here: /var/www/vhosts/system/kaikacampus.com/etc/php.ini . (it's a server by the way). How do I locate this file? I think I'm able to see only the files in the root directory.

Comment: In your shell type in `php -i | grep -e 'Loaded Configuration'` first instead. Which file-name does that give you?

Comment: `/etc/php.ini` and the same error message from the red area.

Comment: Then do the configuration change in that file `/etc/php.ini` and choose your default timezone for PHP in CLI on that server. Do you know how you edit a file?

Comment: I cannot find the directory `etc/` in the root directory when I checked it in filemanager

Comment: I could access the file through the shell. Is it possible to edit it though shell?

Comment: Updated the timzone. When the compsoer update is performed again, the error message for the timezone is gone. But everything upto `phpunit.xml.dist` still shows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a timezone for your server/computer.

You should first locate your php.ini file. You will find the path of it in the output of this command:

`php -i | grep -e 'Loaded Configuration'`

Then load it in your browser (for example `http://localhost/info.php`) and check in the page that opens where your php.ini is located.

When you know where it is, open the php.ini file, look for`date.timezone` setting, change it and save the file.

Comment: I found the location. It is here: `/var/www/vhosts/system/kaikacampus.com/etc/php.ini` . (it's a server by the way). How do I locate this file? I think I'm able to see only the files in the root directory.

Comment: @user1012181: Caution. It's not phpinfo(). This is on the command-line, just `$ php -i | grep -e 'Loaded Configuration'` otherwise you only read the location of your webservers PHP configuration file which can be different. Likewise there is no reloading of Apache as the webserver is unrelated to the operation of composer.

Comment: ouch! :) completely missed that

Comment: @user1012181: I guess you have an etc directory somewhere in your root folder.

Comment: I cheked the file manager, and there is no etc directory in the root folder

Comment: if you don't find any of system, kaikacampus.com, or etc directory in your root folder, then I suggest you to ask the technical support of your hosting provider.

Comment: I can access it through the shell. How can I edit it though the shell?

Comment: Updated the timzone. When the compsoer update is performed again, the error message for the timezone is gone. But everything upto `phpunit.xml.dist` still shows.